# On hover mega menu doesn't appears

Tags: jquery, html, css

[image]below is my code, its working perfect but the problem is when im giving scroll to my left panel mega menu appears inside the left panel. but i want is to appear outside of the panel whether its scrollable or unscrollable. "try removing (max-height: 150px; overflow: auto;) in the class ".maindiv" and hover your mouse on any of the list (ul>li) above and you will understand whats happening exactly.  (I HAVE ATTACHED AN SNAPSHOT WHICH IS EXACTLY WHAT I WANT)

```css
.mainediv {
  background: #444;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 0;
  max-height: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.mainediv ul li {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.mainediv ul li a {
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
}

.megamenu {
  background: #ccc;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
}

.mainediv ul li a:hover {
  background: #ccc;
}

.mainediv ul li:hover .megamenu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2 mainediv">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">hover 1</a>
        <div class="megamenu">
          mega 1
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">hover 2</a>
        <div class="megamenu">
          mega 2
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">hover 3</a>
        <div class="megamenu">
          mega 3
        </div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">hover 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">hover 5</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">hover 6</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">hover 7</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">hover 8</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `overflow-x: visible` and `overflow-y: auto` may not work together, if that is what you are looking to...

Comment: no no... panel scrolling is perfect the only problem is when you will hover on any links of the left panel hovered items is not appearing outside instead its visible's inside the left panel. which is totally incorrect

Comment: let me explain, when you hover on the list it will work perfectly but the problem is there could me more than 100 links on the left panel so i want is that after the height 150px left panel will scroll automatically which is perfect already. the only problem is when im scrolling my left panel the hover item visible's inside and visitor will be needing to scroll horizontally in order to watch the mega menu which is totally incorect what should happen is when somebody hover on the link mega menu should visible outside not inside the scrolable left panel, hope you understand what i want exctly

Comment: yup, I got it... when there *is* vertical scrolling,  you *can't* have horizontally overflowing elements *visible*

Comment: I HAVE ADDED AN SNAPSHOT ABOVE SHOWING WHAT I WANT EXACTLY, PLS HAVE A LOOK

Answer (score 0):

Use `left: 100%;` to resolve your issue.

```css
.mainediv {
  background: #444;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 0;
  /*max-height: 150px;
  overflow: auto;*/
}

.mainediv ul li {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
}

.mainediv ul li a {
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
}

.megamenu {
  background: #ccc;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
}

.mainediv ul li a:hover {
  background: #ccc;
}

.mainediv ul li:hover .megamenu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2 mainediv">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">hover 1</a>
        <div class="megamenu">
          mega 1
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">hover 2</a>
        <div class="megamenu">
          mega 2
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">hover 3</a>
        <div class="megamenu">
          mega 3
        </div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">hover 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">hover 5</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">hover 6</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">hover 7</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">hover 8</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: ahhh, think you didn't understand my question. it is important to make it scrollable on the max height of 150px. i cant just let it 100% by height or width.

Comment: Can you add any snap of your requirement?

Comment: i dont know how to add snap here, there is no any option to add snap in the comment box

Comment: I HAVE ADDED AN SNAPSHOT ABOVE SHOWING WHAT I WANT EXACTLY, PLS HAVE A LOOK

Answer (score 0):

I have created the code below. I think, this is the better way you can do.
I used `jquery` to get the left of `megamenu` by getting the `outerWidth` of the `li` tag and its `top` through `position().top` of the `li`.

Then, added class to `li` every time this is hover. Next, added background to the child `a` having that classname. Here's the updated [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/88108n9s/) too.

```js
$('.mainediv ul li').hover(function(){
    $(this).find('.megamenu').css('top', $(this).position().top);
  $(this).find('.megamenu').css('left', $(this).outerWidth());
  $(this).toggleClass('bg');
});
```

```css
*{ box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0; margin: 0; }

.mainediv {
  background: #444;
  width: 200px;
  height: 250px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.mainediv ul li {
  display: block;
}

.mainediv ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
}

.megamenu {
  background: #ccc;
  height: 200px;
  width: 50%;
  display: none;
  position: absolute
}
.mainediv ul li:hover > .megamenu{
  display: block;
}
.mainediv ul li a:hover, .mainediv ul li.bg a{
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2 mainediv">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">hover 1</a>
        <div class="megamenu">
          mega 1
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">hover 2</a>
        <div class="megamenu">
          mega 2
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">hover 3</a>
        <div class="megamenu">
          mega 3
        </div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">hover 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">hover 5</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">hover 6</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">hover 7</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">hover 8</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this will help you. :)

Comment: sorry to say @bellabelle, but its not correct actually when im scrolling down and hovering on any of the link hovered item taking too much blank space.. try scrolling down first and then hover on any item...